# Sequence with an infinite amount of limit points

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find a sequence which has an infinite amount of limit points.

I was thinking about using the bijective pairing function $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N,\langle x,y\rangle=\binom{x+y+1}{2}+x$ with $\pi_1(\langle x,y\rangle)=x$ and $\pi_2(\langle x,y\rangle)=y$ to describe the sequence

$$a_n=\frac{\pi_1(n)}{\pi_2(n)}.$$

In this case all numbers in $\Bbb Q$ are part of $a_n$, thus all numbers from $\Bbb R$ should be limit points due to $\Bbb Q$ being dense in $\Bbb R$.

Is this solution right or do you have an even easier solution?

Comment: Easier and more intuitive : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9319/sinn-subsequence-limits-set

Comment: You could find a sequence that takes a number on the unit circle, and rotates it by an irrational angle, meaning it will never return to its end point and eventually 'cover' the entire unit circle.

Comment: @user45878 Be carefull there - speaking in radians, the full circle has *angle* $2\pi$, which *is* irrational. In fact, in radians, any *rational* angle will work. The condition you're looking for is that $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$ isn't rational, or in other words that $\theta$ and $\pi$ are incommensurable.

Comment: Choose any enumeration of the rationals. Then each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is a cluster point (limit point) of $(x_n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X_n$ be the largest prime factor of $n$. All primes numbers will be limit points of this sequence. As there are an infinite number of prime numbers, we get the desired sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s yet another example: Let $\{\lambda_n\}_n$ be an enumeration of all rational numbers; we know this can be done in many different explicit ways. Then every real number is a limit point of this sequence.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence accumulating on all $0\le x \le 1$ can be constructed as:
First fix an intger $k$, for.example $k=5$. Then
$$
    x_n = n/k,   \qquad 0 \le n \le k
$$
Continue by
$$
    x_n = \frac{n-k}{2k}  \quad  k+1\le n \le 3k
$$, and finally, for each $i$,
$$
    x_n = \frac{n-(2^i-1)k}{2^i k} ,\quad   (2^i-1)k+1 \le n \le (2^{i+1}-1)k
$$
This sequence will have an uncountable number of accumulation points.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer:
{ 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, ..., n, n-1, ..., 2, 1, ...}