# Is $\sum (\sin n)^n$ diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I saw this series incidentally:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sin n)^n $$
Result from WolframAlpha seems to say the series diverges but I don't know how to prove it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: If we show $\left\{\{\frac{n}{2\pi}\}|n>N, n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ is a dense set in $(0;1)$ $\forall N\in \mathbb{N}$ then $\left(\frac{\sin^{-1}(\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2}})}{2\pi};\frac{\pi-\sin^{-1}(\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2}})}{2\pi}\right)$ always contains a number $x$ for which $\sin^n (2\pi x)>\frac{1}{2}$ so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sin^n(n)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have a series converge, you must have the summands approach $0$ as a limit.  Although intuitively you might think that $-1<\sin(n)<1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and therefore $(\sin(n))^n$ acts like $r^n$ with $-1<r<1$ and will converge, this seems to fail.

> **Lemma:** For each $x\in[-1,1]$, there exists a subsequence of $A_n=\sin(n)$ such that $\lim\limits_{n_j\to\infty} A_{n_j}=x$

For proof of the lemma, see [sin(n) subsequence limits set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9319/sinn-subsequence-limits-set)

So then, there exist infinitely many $n$ for which $\sin(n)\geq 1-\frac{1}{n}$, and therefore infinitely many $n$ for which $(\sin(n))^n>\frac{1}{e}$.  Therefore the sequence of partial sums will always have some sudden jumps and cannot converge.

Comment: JMoravitz> "So then, there exist infinitely many $n$ for which $\sin(n)≥1−\frac1n$." Does this follow from the lemma? I doubt. Then $\forall n$ there exist infinitely many $n_k$ for which $\sin(n_k)≥1−\frac1n$. But what follows from this?

Comment: @grizzly It has been quite a while since I visited this question.  Lets see... My claim was that the lemma implied that there are infinitely many $n$ for which $\sin(n)\geq 1-\frac{1}{n}$ (*not that given a specific $n$ there are infinitely many $n_k$ such that $\sin(n_k)\geq 1-\frac{1}{n}$*).  If this claim happened to be true, then we could show that there is an infinite subsequence of $a_n=\sin(n)^n$ for which $a_n>\frac{1}{e}$ as we would have had for those values of $n$ that $\sin(n)^n\geq (1-\frac{1}{n})^n>\frac{1}{e}$.  This would imply that $a_n$ does not converge to zero.

Comment: Knowing that $\sin(n)^n$ does not converge to zero, this implies by the $n$'th term divergence test that the series could not converge either.  (*If a series converges, then the summands must converge to zero.  If the summands do not converge to zero, then the series diverges*).  Looking back on this, I feel like I thought my claim was obvious but it is not obvious to me now.  I still feel like it should intuitively be true, but I would have to think on it further to prove it.  Thankfully, there is already another linked answer which shows $\sin(n)^n$ diverges, implying the final step.

Comment: I will delete my answer after a few hours once you've had a chance to read this since I cannot back up that claim.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I understood your comment. I'm glad if my comment was useful.