# Help to find example where $\sup\{a_nb_n|n\in N\}> \sup\{a_n|n\in N\}\sup\{b_n|n\in N\}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

In the past few hours I'm trying to find an example where $$\sup\{a_nb_n|n\in N\}> \sup\{a_n|n\in N\}\sup\{b_n|n\in N\}$$
But I just can't find it, can someone see what I miss here?

**EDIT: $a_n,b_n$ are both bounded from above and below**

Comment: your example does not work. You get $1>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

$$a_n =
\begin{cases}
-2,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
-3, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

$$b_n =
\begin{cases}
-3,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
-2, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

Then you get $6>4$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_n = \{ \frac{1-n}{n} \} $ and $B_n = \{ \sin(n) \} $.

Notice $\sup A_n = 0 $ and $\sup B_n = 1 $ and $\sup (A_n B_n) = 2 $

Comment: Is it obvious that $\sup\left(\{\sin(n)\colon n\in \mathbb N\}\right)=1$?

Comment: are you asking me this question or you are asking yourself or you are asking  to the asker ?

Comment: I'm asking you and myself I guess.

Comment: To be honest, the fact that $| \sin x | \leq 1 $ gives the intution. However, since $n$ is integer, $\sin n $ never hits $1$. So, I would say the proof of this fact is not as easy. I dont know how to prove it right now.

Comment: See [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484131/what-is-sup-sinn) and [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63526/showing-sup-sin-n-mid-n-in-mathbb-n-1).