# Finding $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of $A_n = (\sin (n) -1,\sin (n) + 1)$?

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

For $n \in \mathbb N^*$, $A_n = (\sin (n) -1,\sin (n) + 1)$.

How to show that $\limsup A_n = [-2,2], \liminf A_n = \{0\}$?

What if $A_n = (\sin (n -1),\sin (n + 1))$ instead?

Comment: Your taking the limsup of a sequence of sets?

Comment: Perhaps you mean for two different sequences? For $sin n-1$ and $sin n+1$?

Comment: Ah sorry, it's a typo. I will edit my question.

Comment: Is it $\sin(n)\pm 1$ or $\sin(n\pm1)$?

Comment: It is the former.

Comment: The question is not accurate. if we talk $\sup$ and $\inf$ in two dimesnion, what is the order of set here?

Comment: @runaround. The question is well defined. Exist the concepts of $\lim\sup$ and $\lim\inf$ for sequences of sets

Comment: Infimum and supremum are defined on sets, while $A_n$ here are two-element sets, so $\sup A_n = \sin n + 1$ and $\inf A_n = \sin n - 1$, neither is even converging. So it is either partial limits meant or *union* of the sets $A$ up to $n$.

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky $A_n$ is the interval $(\sin(n)-1,\sin(n)+1)$. Then, by definition, $\lim\sup A_n=\cap_{n=1}^\infty\cup_{m=n}^\infty A_n$ and $\lim\inf A_n=\cup_{n=1}^\infty\cap_{m=n}^\infty A_n$

Comment: @sinbadh Oops. Didn't mention that the brackets aren't curved...

Comment: @sinbadh, that is what I am wondering from question. THX.

Comment: @SiXUlm: your extra question is interesting.

Comment: @c.robert sorry, I don't mean to edit directly your post. Just don't know how to undo it.

Answer (score 2):

Given a sequence of sets $A_1, A_2, \ldots$, the lim sup of the $A_n$ is the set of points that are seen in *infinitely many* of the $A_n$, while $\liminf A_n$ is the set of points that are seen in *all but a finite number* of the $A_n$.

Your sets $A_n$ are intervals of radius $1$ centered on $\sin(n)$. As $n$ varies, the centers of these intervals weave back and forth between $-1$ and $1$ (visiting points in between). I agree that every point between $-2$ and $2$ (exclusive) must be visited infinitely often by your $A_n$, since [$\{\sin(n):n=1,2,\ldots\}$ is dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4764/215011) in the interval $[-1,1]$, which implies that for every small $\epsilon>0$ there exists infinitely many $n$ for which $\sin(n)>1-\epsilon$; for those $n$ we have $2-\epsilon<\sin(n)+1$, which means $2-\epsilon\in A_n$. Similarly there are infinitely many $n$ for which $-2+\epsilon\in A_n$. But $\sin(n)$ is never $-1$ or $1$ when $n$ is an integer (since $\pi$ is irrational), so $-2$ and $2$ do not belong to any of the $A_n$. Conclude $\limsup A_n=(-2,2)$.

As for the lim inf, only the point $0$ is found in every $A_n$, since $-1<\sin(n)<1$ for every integer $n$. Any nonzero number won't belong to $\liminf A_n$, because if $\epsilon >0$ then (by the same claim as cited earlier) there are infinitely many $n$ where $\sin(n)>1-\epsilon$. For those $n$ we have $-\epsilon<\sin(n)-1$, which means $-\epsilon\not\in A_n$. Similiarly if $\epsilon <0$ then there are infinitely many $n$ for which $\epsilon\not\in A_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Note you only need to know $\limsup \sin n $ and $\liminf \sin n$ to solve this.

The $\limsup$ part has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484131/what-is-sup-sinn), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63526/showing-sup-sin-n-mid-n-in-mathbb-n-1), the $\inf$ part should be similar.

Comment: Thanks. However I don't really understand why $\liminf$ reduces to one point?