# Supremum of the sequence $\sin (n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum, cauchy-sequences

I am wondering how to prove that the supremum of the following sequence is 1
$$a_n=\sin (n)$$

Comment: The Kronecker density theorem. Look at this page: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484131/what-is-sup-sinn

Comment: Actuually, $\{\sin n\mid n\in\mathbf N\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.