# Proving $\sup \{\sin n:n \in \mathbb{N}\} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Consider the set
$$A=\{\sin n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
How should I proceed to prove that $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A = 1$? Is there a direct proof? Can any argument be provided via reductio ad absurdum?

Comment: I don't understand why somebody votes to close the question without even providing any argument regarding the reason to do so! This question is purely motivated from the abstract definition of supremum that I have problem understanding.

Comment: I know a few proofs, but no elementary ones

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63526/showing-sup-sin-n-mid-n-in-mathbb-n-1

Comment: Also see (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484131/what-is-sup-sinn?noredirect=1&lq=1)