# Show that $\limsup$ of $\sin n$ is 1

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

I want to prove that the $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin n=1$. I know that $1$ is an upper bound for $\sin n$ but I cannot find a subsequence of $\sin n$ that converges to $1$. Can somebody help me construct such a subsequence?

Comment: $\sin\left(n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63526/showing-sup-sin-n-mid-n-in-mathbb-n-1

Comment: @cand sorry but that is not a subsequence of $\{\sin n\}$.

Comment: @cand I think he meant $n \in \mathbb N$

Comment: Can't you just use the ergodic theorem on the circle (which is easy to prove directly) to say that there are integers that get arbitrarily close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (working modulo $2\pi$, of course)?

Comment: A sketch of a direct method: find a sequence of positive integers $x_n$ and a sequence of positive integers $y_n$ which are equivalent to $1$ mod $4$ such that $q_n = x_n/y_n \to \pi/2$. Then certainly $\sin(q_n) \to 1$. Try to make the convergence sufficiently rapid as $y_n$ grows that $\sin(x_n) = \sin(y_n q_n)  \to 1$. This "make the convergence rapid as $y_n$ grows" idea leads naturally into continued fraction expansion.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1

Answer (score 0):

There is a theorem by Kronecker (?) that says that the grid in $\Bbb R$ generated by $1$ and some number $r$ is either dense or an arithmetic progression, obviously corresponding to the cases $r$ irrational or rational.

In this case it means that the sequence of integers modulo $2\pi$ is dense in the interval $[0,2\pi)$, and thus the set of values $\sin(n)$ dense in the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Is there a way we can find the sequence in concrete terms?

Comment: Which sequence, and what does "concrete terms" mean?

Comment: Can we get a certain subsequence of $N$ such that $\sin$ of the sequence converges to 1?