# Using the root test for convergence and getting stuck

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> I have to establish the convergence of the following series:
>   $$\sum_{n \ge1}\left(2+\sin n\right)^n\left(1-\dfrac{2}{n}\right)^{n^2}.$$

Using the root test I obviously obtained:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2+\sin n\right)\left(1-\dfrac{2}{n}\right)^{n}.$$ Does this limit even exist? I know that the limit of the second sequence is $e^{-2}$, but the sequence which contains $\sin n$ doesn't have a limit. Also, taken as a whole I don't know how to compute the limit. 
If it is indeed the case that it doesn't have a limit, then the root test is inconclusive so what test could I apply? 
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint. For the  [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test), you are supposed to find
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(2+\sin n\right)\left(1-\dfrac{2}{n}\right)^{n}\right).$$

Comment: Oh, I see. So we get $3e^{-2}$ taking the sin as 1, right?

Comment: Yes. You may also say that the $\limsup\leq 3/e^2<1$. $\limsup\sin n=1$ but it is not a trivial result. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276422/show-that-limsup-of-sin-n-is-1

Comment: Yeah. So the initial series is convergent! Thanks a lot!