# Convergence of $\sin(nx)$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sine function dense in $[-1,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1)

Does there exist a subsequence $n_k$ where $1\leq k < \infty $ of the sequence of natural numbers, such that the sequence $\sin n_k$ is convergent?

Comment: Question and title don't match.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in fact, given any $x$, $-1\le x\le1$, there's a subsequence such that $\sin n_k$ converges to $x$. In other words, $\sin n$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Well, yes... But I was stumped on the proof.

Comment: Then maybe you should edit your question so that it asks what you really want to ask. Anyway, I imagine a web search for "sine" and "dense" will turn up proofs galore.

Comment: Hint: if $\alpha$ is irrational, then $\{{n\alpha\}}$, the set of fractional parts of $n\alpha$, as $n$ runs through the natural numbers, is dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson and $\{n\alpha\}$ is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$, as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Frank, I know that, but it's overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Every bounded real sequence has a convergent subsequence.

This is known as [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

This answers your original question. However, as you can see from other answers and comments, about this particular sequence you can show even more than that.