# Subsequential limit of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to determine all subsequential limit points of the following sequence

```
X_n = cos(n)
```

Not sure how to decompose this into subsequences.

Anyone know how to tackle this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is rather well known that the image of the integers under sine and cosine is dense in $[-1, 1]$. For a reference, see the related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1).

**edit in response to op's comment**

With the knowledge that $\cos(n)$ is dense in $[-1, 1]$, we shall show that any $x\in[-1,1]$ is a sub-sequential limit point. Indeed, given any $\epsilon > 0$ and some $n_0 > 0$, we can find $n > n_0$ such that 
$$\cos(n) \in (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$$
so we can iteratively pick a sub-sequence that lies within this $\epsilon$-neighborhood. This shows that any point is a sub-sequential limit point of the sequence.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Ah, very true. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Does that mean all subsequential limit points fall between [0,1]? I'm having trouble relating density to subsequential limits.

Comment: It means that every point in $[0,1]$ is a sub-sequential limit point. I will make an edit to make this more explicit.

Comment: The link you posted earlier said that cos(n) is dense in [-1,1].

Comment: My mistake, it should be $[-1, 1]$. For some reason I was interpreting the sequence as positive. The argument still holds though. Every point in $[-1, 1]$ is a limit point of the sequence.

Comment: Minor nitpickery: while it still follows easily from density, you might want to note that you can find a 'sufficiently large' $n$ satisfying your condition; in particular, given $\epsilon$ and some $n_0$, you can find $n\gt n_0$ s.t. $\cos(n)\in(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ - this lets you produce an increasing sequence of $n$s.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki I've added the corrections. Thank you.