# limit computation $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln (1+n^{3})-\ln(n^{6})}{\sin ^{3}(n)} $.

Tags: calculus, limits

Help me please to compute this limit:
$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln (1+n^{3})-\ln(n^{6})}{\sin ^{3}(n)} $.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Manzano That is not true. It does not vanish for any $n\in \Bbb N$. $\sin x=0\iff x=k\pi \;,k\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Maple says it doesn't exist. Are we supposed to search two sequences for violating the limit?

Comment: @BabakSorouh It doesn't exist because the logs go to $-\infty$ but the sine oscilates infinitely often.

Comment: So true, Peter.

Comment: About the character of the sequence $(\sin n)$: [Sine function dense in $\[-1,1\]$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac{\ln (1+n^3) - \ln (n^6)}{\sin^3 n} = \frac{\ln n}{\sin^3 n} \left(\frac{\ln(1+n^3)}{\ln n} - \frac{\ln(n^6)}{\ln n}\right).
$$
The expression in the right brackets tend to $-3$. Thus it suffices to consider the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{\sin^3 n}.
$$
Since $\ln n\to \infty$ and $0<|\sin n|\leqslant 1$, we get that in absolute value the limit is infinity. However, as $\sin^3 n$ changes signs infinitely often, the limit does not exist.