# Cluster point of a set

Tags: calculus

Given a sequence $a_{n}=\sin nx$,$n=1,2,...$,where $x\in(0,\pi)$,what is the limit point of the sequence?

It's non-empty by Weierstrass theorem,but is there more information we know about it?
Is it finite or infinite?Or even dense in $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Depends on $x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrewsIs there possibility that it's dense in $[-1,1]$?I mean, for some fixed $x$?

Comment: It's mostly certainly possible for it to be dense - if $x/\pi$ is not rational, then $\sin nx$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrewsMmm...how can i find a rigorous proof for this?

Comment: You can find a proof that $\{\sin(n)\}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$ here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1 The methods at that answer suffice to prove Thomas Andrews' claim above.

Comment: @BenjaminDickmanIt's really helpful,much appreciate bro!By the way it's a big surprise that you had been here in Nanjing!

Comment: Note that the set of limit  points of a sequence is always closed. Thus, saying that it is "dense in..." is the same as saying "equal to...".

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\sin n\frac\pi2=\begin{cases}\;\;\,0&,\;\;n\;\;\text{is even}\\{}\\-1&,\;\;n\;\;\text{is}\;\;3\pmod 4\\{}\\\;\;\,1&,\;\;n\;\;\text{is}\;\;1\pmod 4\end{cases}$$

and you already have three cluster points. Check what happens with some other values of $\;x\;$ ...

Comment: Depends - he the original question asked for cluster points of a set, not cluster points of a sequence. Also, it is unclear from the question whether $x$ is allowed to vary, or is fixed.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure whether $\;x\;$ varies or not, either, but for the above particular value of $\;x\;$ there is no *one* cluster point, but several.

Comment: No, in that case, $A=\{-1,0,+1\}$ which has zero cluster points. The sequence $0,1,0,-1,....$ has three cluster points. That was my point about the distinction between limit points of a set and a sequence.

Comment: @ThomasAndrewsOh it's my fault,I mean the limit points of a sequence

Comment: @CWeid Yeah, I guessed as much, was just pointing out the problem *as stated* wouldn't give any cluster (limit) points.

Comment: Well,  what I really meant above was with $\;x\;$ a variable