# Is $\{ \sin n^m \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ dense in $[-1,1]$ for every natural number $m$?

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, problem-solving

Is $\{\sin n^m \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ dense in $[-1,1]$ for every natural number $m$?

---

#### Progress

For $m=1$, I can prove this using the fact that $\sin$ is continuous and $a+b\pi$ is dense in the real line, for integer $a$ and $b$. However, this approach breaks down for $m>1$; what method should be used then?

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on what you've tried in answering the question so that we can best direct our assistance.

Comment: @Arkamis The whole 'what have you tried' business, in my unsophisticated opinion, only makes sense for questions that are not obviously non-trivial. Sure, the OP should have included that he knows the statement for $m=1$ and maybe a [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1?rq=1) to a solution, but other than that the question is obviously interesting and non-trivial. @ OP Note that it would suffice that $a+b^2\pi$ is dense but I _think_ problems like that usually boil down to questions about approximations of $\pi$ that are known to be 'out-of-reach' hard.

Comment: @Myself I disagree. Asking what the poster has tried isn't just a matter of making them put more effort into the question, but also guides possible responses in such a way that they present useful information to the OP. A great example is the bevy of linear algebra answers that invoke the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. The answers are great -- assuming the OP knows (and can use) that theorem.

Comment: Can we extend solution for $m=1$ to general case? we can  project (continous function) $(a+b\pi)^m$ to $a$ and use similar statement as for $m=1$.

Comment: @Myself To be fair, this is a fairly standard exercise in equidistribution theory, so this particular one isn't out-of-reach :).  It's still unclear whether the OP has any background in Weyl's method, but it's looking less likely after the followup comments.  In fact one does extend the $m=1$ solution to higher $m$ by Weyl differencing, but I can't make any sense of the phrase "project $(a+b\pi)^m$ to $a$"

Comment: Define a (projection) function that sends every $(a+b\pi)^m$ to $a$. It's continuous and hence sends dense set to $a^n^ dense.

Comment: @user180168 Thanks, that makes much more sense as a concept, but it is a deeply flawed approach.  The $\sin()$ is a crucial part of the density of $a$.  Extricating that while preserving any notion of continuous function will prove to be subtle if not impossible.  For instance, the map $n \mapsto \pi n$ is continuous (in either direction) but I think you'll agree that $\{\sin n\}$ and $\{\sin \pi n\}$ behave very differently.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

Given any real number $x_0$, the map $T_{x_0} : (x_1,\ldots,x_d) \mapsto (x_1+x_0,x_2+x_1,\ldots,x_d+x_{d-1})$ from $(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})^d$ to itself preserves the Haar probability measure. When $x_0$ is an irrational number, it is ergodic. This can be checked by using Fourier series.

A recursion shows that for every integer $n \ge 0$ and $(x_1,\ldots,x_d) \in (\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})^d$,
$$T_{x_0} ^n(x_1,\ldots,x_d) = \Big(x_1+x_0~,~x_2+nx_1+{n \choose 2}x_0~,~\ldots~,~\sum_{k=0}^d {n \choose k} x_{d-k}\Big).$$
Applying Birkoff ergodic theorem to any integrable fonction depending on the last variable $x_d$ only yields the following statement.

If $P$ is a non-constant polynomial whose leading coefficient is irrational, then the sequence $(P(n))_{n \ge 0}$ is uniformly distributed modulo 1.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence

In particular, the sequence $(n^m/(2\pi))_{n \ge 0}$ is uniformly distributed modulo 1, yielding the positive answer to your question.