# What is the infimum of this sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

What is the answer of $\inf\limits_{k\geq 1,k\in \mathbb{N}} |\sin(k^2)|$?
It may be $0$, just like $\inf |\sin(k)| = 0$ for $k\geq 1,k\in \mathbb{N}$.
How to prove it?

Comment: Related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325386/can-we-extend-the-proof-of-density-of-sinn-to-sinn2