# What is the range of $p$ that causes $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(\sin n)^p}$ to converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to use Jordan Inequality, i.e.
$$\sin x\le \frac{2x}{\pi }\text,$$
but I don't know how.

Comment: The Jordan inequality is $\sin x\ge 2x/\pi$, and it only holds for $x\in[0,\pi/2]$. But $|\sin x| \le |x|$ holds for all $x$.

Answer (score 3):

[$(\sin n)^p$ is dense in $[-1,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1084945/399263)
so the general term of this series does not go to $0$ and the series diverge.

Edit: *I notice that the link have the restriction $p$ integer, so this is only a partial result. The proof need to be examined if it can be extended to real values.*

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I realized that the sum is ill-defined for most real $p$. So you can apply the below to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\sin n\right|^{-p}$.

If $p\ge 0$, it trivially diverges. So I will try to show that $\{\sin^{q} n, n\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$ for $q>0$ (corresponding to $p<0$), and then zwim's answer takes us home.

I assume we know that $\{\sin n\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$. Let $x\in[0,1]$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Let $f(x)=x^\frac1q$. Then there is an $n_0\in \mathbb N$ such that
$$
\sin n_0 \in f((x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon)\cap [0,1])
$$
because $\{\sin n\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$. But that shows that
$$
\sin^q n_0\in (x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon)\cap [0,1]
$$
so $\{\sin^q n\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

This seems too simple compared to zwim's link. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

$\sin n$ can be as small as you want, take $n=\lfloor k\pi\rfloor$ with $\{k\pi\}<\epsilon$. No positive value of $p$ will do.

Comment: @Milten: the question is asked in a weird way, then.