# Convergence of the series with sum of sines in denominator

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does this series converge?

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sin 1 + \sin 2 + \ldots + \sin n}
$$

What test do I have to use for it?

Comment: What tests do you know and what have you tried?

Comment: First thing is to check whether the terms tend to $0$. Can you find a more tractable form for $$\sum_{k = 1}^n \sin k\,?$$

Comment: You might consider the sum of the first $43$, $665$, and $709$ terms, related to $\pi \approx \frac{22}{7}, \frac{333}{106}, \frac{355}{113}, \ldots$

Answer (score 3):

[We have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro):
$$ \sin(1)+\sin(2)+\ldots+\sin(n) = \text{Im}\sum_{j=1}^{n}e^{ji} = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sin(1)+\sin(2)+\ldots+\sin(n)}=2\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\tag{2}$$
but since the sequence given by $a_n = \exp\left(\frac{i}{2}+in\right)$ [is dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1) in the unit circle, the general term of our series is not even bounded, hence the series cannot be convergent. An alternative proof, following Kelenner's comment below, comes from noticing that $\left|\frac{1}{\sin(1)+\sin(2)+\ldots+\sin(n)}\right|\geq\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$

Comment: I think that you can simplify: let $u_n$ the sum of the $\sin(k)$, you have proven that $ |u_n|\leq 1/\sin(1/2)$, so $1/u_n$ does not go to $0$..

Comment: @Kelenner: that's true. Not only the general term is unbounded, but it is bounded away from a neighbourhood of zero. Two good reasons for which the series cannot be convergent.