# What is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n ^ {(1 + \sin{(n)})}} {\sqrt{n}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

What is the value of this limit :

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n ^ {(1 + \sin{(n)})}} {\sqrt{n}}$$

The original question was to find out the asymptotic relation between $n^{(1 + \sin{(n)})}$ and $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: The limit does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

For infinitely many $n$, $\sin n < -3/4$,  so along this subsequence, $$\frac{n^{1+\sin n}}{\sqrt{n}} ≤ n^{-1/4} → 0.$$

However, for infinitely many other $n$, $\sin n >  0$, so here we see
$$ \frac{n^{1+\sin n}}{\sqrt n} ≥ n^{1/2} → ∞. $$

Comment: Can you please explain?how this statement coming?
For infinitely many $n, sinn<−3/4$  so along this subsequence,

Comment: @Maneesh.Maths are you asking why $\{\sin(n) : n≥0\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$? I suggest reading the answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1

Comment: Now I understood. I forgot this result.thank you.

Comment: You do not need the density result. All you need is for $e^{in}$ to land infinitely many times in the arc centered at $(-1,0)$ having length $>\pi/3.$

Comment: @zhw. You are of course right, that was just the first related question I found that had good answers.