# Show that infinitely many $n$ exists for $c$ and $k$ that $|\sin(n^k)|<c$

Tags: inequality, irrational-numbers

For any positive number $c$ and positive integer $k$, show that there are infinitely many positive integer $n$ that satisfy

$$|\sin(n^k)| < c$$

I proved the case when $k=1$, but I can't solve when $k\geq2$.

Comment: You could try 2 dimensional proof by induction.

Comment: Could [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764) be helpful?

Comment: This is a direct consequence of the fact that $\{n^a \}$ is equidistributed modulo $2\pi$ for any $a>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [Weyl's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality) and [the equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem), the irrationality of $\pi$ implies that $e^{i f(n)}$ is equidistributed (hence dense) on the unit circle for any $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Since the map $z\to \text{Im}(z)$ is continuous it preserves density and the claim is a straightforward consequence.