# When does this limit equal $1$? $\;\;\lim _{n \to \infty} n^{\beta - \alpha - \sin(n)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

$$\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{\beta}}{n^{\alpha + \sin(n)}} = \lim _{n \to \infty} n^{\beta - \alpha - \sin(n)} $$

if $\beta - \alpha < -2 $

the limit is clearly $0$

if on the other hand $\beta - \alpha > 2$

limit is $+\infty$

for the case $\beta = \alpha = 0$ I think the limit doesn't exist

but I can't see how the limit could possibly be $1$ as $\beta - \alpha -\sin(n)$ acts randomly for big $n$'s so it's no way steadily near $0$

Comment: if $\beta = \alpha$ then you have $n^{sin(n)}$

Comment: You've left out consideration of $-2\lt \beta-\alpha \lt 2$.

Comment: and natural log of that ... $sin(n) \ln n$

Comment: can't have a limit since sin vascillates from positive to negative?

Comment: That should be $n^{-\sin(n)}$, when $\beta = \alpha$, @phdmba7of12

Comment: @amWhy yeah I know Ive left cases, it's because I couldn't treat them lol

Comment: why do you have two constants? easier to think about it as $n^{c-\sin n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\{\sin(n)\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.
This means the set of limit points of the sequence $\big(\sin(n)\big)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is $[-1,1]$, ie, for any $x\in[-1,1]$ there is a subsequence $n_k$ with $\sin(n_k) \to x$ as $k\to\infty$.

For details, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1).
Basically, it is a consequence of the fact that any additive group in the reals is either discrete of the form $a\mathbb Z$, or else dense (and this in turn follows basically from division with remainder).

It follows that $\{\beta - \alpha - \sin(n)\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}$ has limit set 
$L=[\beta-\alpha-1,\beta-\alpha+1]$.
We hence have the cases:

- If $\beta-\alpha-1>0$, then $n^{\beta-\alpha-\sin(n)}>n^{\beta-\alpha-1}$.
  Since the latter goes to $+\infty$ as $n\to+\infty$, so does the former.
- If $\beta - \alpha +1 < 0$, then $0<n^{\beta-\alpha-\sin(n)}<n^{\beta-\alpha+1}$.
  Since the latter goes to $0$ as $n\to+\infty$, by the squeeze theorem, so does the former.
- If $\beta-\alpha-1 = 0$, then $L$ contains positive elements as well as $0$.
  In this case, we can find subsequences that diverge to $+\infty$ or go to $1$ as $n\to+\infty$.
  In particular, the limit does not exist.
- If $\beta-\alpha+1 = 0$, then $L$ contains negative elements as well as $0$.
  In this case, we can find subsequences that go to $0$ or go to $1$ as $n\to+\infty$.
  In particular, the limit does not exist.
- Finally, if $-1<\beta-\alpha< 1$, then $L$ contains both positive and negative elements, as well as $0$.
  In this case, we can find subsequences that diverge to $+\infty$, go to $0$ or go to $1$ as $n\to+\infty$.
  In particular, the limit does not exist.

To specifically answer your question, the limit is never $1$, but sometimes it is guaranteed to be $0$ or $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

To have limit equal to $1$ we need as necessary condition that

$${\beta - \alpha - \sin(n)}\to 0$$

which is never true since that limit doesn't exist.