# nature of series discussion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

the series : $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha+\sin(n)}}$$

according to answers to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803334/when-does-this-limit-equal-1-lim-n-to-infty-n-beta-alpha-s) I previously asked here on MSE

there's no way I can compare to a p-series.

it's been some time that I encountered this series and I still have no idea how to tackle it.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I do not understand what you do not like about the answer given to the prior question. It proves that for $\alpha >1$ the limit is 0, for $\alpha < -1$ the limit is $\infty$ and for the other cases, the limit does not exist.

Comment: @Fabian I didn't say I didn't like the answer given there. Im just saying thanks to the answers now I know trying to make a comparison test with a p-series is impossible