# Determine for what values of $x$ the series converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Determine for what values of $x$ the series converges.

Here is the series:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{\sin^n n}.$$

**My trial:**
 Considering $a_{n} = \frac{1}{\sin^n n} $

I calculated $|\frac{a_{n+1} x^{n+1}}{a_n x^n}|$ which is equal to $|x||\frac{\sin^n n}{\sin^{n+1}(n+1)}|$  then I want to take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ but then what shall I do? I do not know how to solve this limit

Comment: you have a power series, and can simply compute its  radius of convergence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence

Comment: I know this information and this is what I am trying to do but I have a difficulty which I mentioned above.@Hayk

Comment: Have you tried the [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test), along with the fact that [$\sin$ is dense in $[-1,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1)?

Comment: No I will try it @ClementC.

Comment: @ClementC. Ithink the limit will not exist by the root test because I will calculate $\lim (1/\sin n)$.... it seems like the root test also does not work.

Comment: The limit does not exist -- but the $\lim\sup$ does and is equal to $+\infty$, which allows you to conclude by the root test @hopefully

Comment: you mean the radius of convergence is zero? @ClementC.

Comment: @hopefully Yes.

Comment: How do you calculated the limit sup of the \sin n function?@ClementC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(Big) hint:** use the [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test), along with the fact that [$(\sin n)_n$ is dense in $[-1,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1).

**In more detail** *(put your mouse on the area to reveal it)*:

> Since $(\sin n)_n$ is dense in $[-1,1]$, there exists a sequence of integers  $(n_k)_k$ such that $\sin n_k \xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{} 0^+$, from which $\sqrt[n_k]{a_{n_k}} = \frac{1}{\sin n_k} \xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{} +\infty$. This means that $\limsup_n \sqrt[n]{a_n} = +\infty$: applying the root test (with $C\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\infty$), you therefore get that the radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{\limsup_n a_n} = 0$.

Comment: could you write the detailed steps for me as I am confused about |\sin n| how I will write its limit?

Comment: @hopefully Done, see my edit. Once again, the root test asks you to consider the $\limsup$ of $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ (which exists), not the limit (which may not exist, and here indeed does not exist).

Comment: I need a proof that the limtsup of sin n is +infinity

Comment: It's in the answer (in the "spoiler"). It's not of $\sin n$, it's of $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$.

Comment: but the problem that we have absolute value of sin n not only sin n ..... so the limit sup is 1 if we take the sequence $(4m +1)\pi/2$

Comment: This doesn't change anything. We are using the existence of a subsequence such that $\sin n_k \to 0^+$; the same subsequence has $|\sin n_k |\to 0^+$.

Comment: why did you choose the sequence that makes the sin converges to zero ..... there are other sequences as I mentioned above that make the sign did not converge to zero

Comment: These other sequences would not help me prove the limsup is infinity... You want to show that to conclude.

Comment: what do you mean by sin being dense in this interval ? what is the importance of the existence of that subsequence if there are many others that doen not converge to zero?

Comment: Those other sequences would only show the limsup is "at least some value".

Comment: does not the limit sup defined as the largest accumulation point?

Comment: If you want to show there exist blue fishes, you find a blue fish and show it to your friends. You don't care about the red, yellow, or green fish. They do exist, but they're not useful to show the existence of blue fishes.

Comment: Yes. The largest. But we want the limsup of 1/sin n, NOT of sin n.

Comment: could you give me an explicit form of that sequence please?

Comment: what do you mean by sin being dense in this interval?

Comment: That every point of [-1,1] is an accumulation point of the sequence (sin n). We only use it for the point 0, though.

Comment: could you give me an explicit form of that sequence please?

Comment: what is C? is it the limit of the root test?

Comment: Yes. I defined C that way for you to read and easily apply the theorem from the Wikipedia link, where it's the notation they use.