# sine sequence maximum with absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

does there exist an integer N such that $|\sin(N)|$ > $|\sin(n)|$ 
for all natural numbers ??
if not what is the proof

Comment: What is $n$ in your question? Is it given in advance?

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): [Sine function dense in $[-1,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative. The sequence $(\sin n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$. Therefore, such an integer $N$ can't exist as $\sin n \neq 1$ for $n \in \mathbb N$.

The proof is based on following facts:

- $G = (\{n + 2p \pi \mid (n,p) \in \mathbb Z^2\}, +)$ is an additive subgroup of the reals.
- The additive subgroups of the real are either discrete or dense.
- $G$ can't be discrete as this would imply that $\pi$ is rational.
- Therefore $G$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.
- As $\sin$ is continuous, $(\sin n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.
- The sinus of an integer is different to $1$.