# Which is the sup and inf of ${\frac{1}{sin(n)}: n \in N}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Considering that we know the $\sup$ and $\inf$ of $\sin(n)$, can we easily find the bounds of $\Bigl\lbrace {\frac{1}{\sin(n)}: n \in \Bbb N}\Bigr\rbrace$ or we have to follow a different way to find them?

**My solution**
We know that $sup(sin(n))$ = 1 and $inf(sin(n))$= -1 and also know that $sin(n)$ is dense in $[-1,1]$, according to this if $\sin(n)$ is close to $0$ then $\frac{1}{\sin(n)}$ is close to infinity. So, the $\frac{1}{\sin(n)}$ is not bounded.

Comment: $\sin(n)$ is never equal to zero.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah If we say that  if sin(n) tends to 0 then the fraction tends to infinity ?

Comment: $\sin(n)$ has no limit when $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah yes, but for a $n \in N$, $sin(n)$ is close to $0$

Comment: $\sin(n) $ is close to zero when $ n$ is close to $ k\pi$.

Comment: perfect, so $1/sin(n)$ is close to infinity ?

Comment: $\{\sin(n)\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: You have to  prove that $\{\sin n\mid n\in\bf N\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: This thread has many great answers regarding density of $\sin(n)$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah so $\frac{1}{sin(n)}$ is not bounded

Comment: @Bernard If we prove this what can we say about $\frac{1}{sin(n))}$ ?

Comment: This implies that we have values of $n$ such that  $0$  can approached by $\sin(n)$ as close as we please, so  $\frac1{\sin(n)}\,\dots$

Comment: @Bernard tends to infinity??? :)

Comment: In absolute value (because there are values of $n$ such that $\sin(n)<0 $, and others for which it is $>0$).

Comment: @Bernard yeap, so the set is not bounded

Comment: @DimitrisDimitriadis: Πράγματι

Comment: Consider convergents of $\pi:\ \frac 31,\frac{22}7,\frac{333}{106},\frac{355}{113},\frac{103993}{33102},\dots$ Then $3\approx \pi$, $22\approx 7\pi$, $333\approx 106\pi$, $355\approx 113\pi$, $103993\approx 33102\pi\dots$. Set $a_n$ as a numerator of $n$-th convergent. Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac 1{|\sin a_n|}=\infty$.